# asked this 2 times but no one helped

Tags: python, video, mobile

I have asked a question two times and both times got no answer. i am stuck and have been trying to figure this out for two days. teaching myself programming is hard!

> I have built [This App](http://finnfrotscher.pythonanywhere.com/). It is build on `Flask`. There is no mobilesupport right now. Because the videoload is rather high, I want
>   to serve the same videos but with a different resolution, cut and
>   filetype when the page is opened on a handheld.
>
> My Questions:
>
> 1: What Filetypes do i have to serve for Mobile.
>
> 2: Should i rather build mobile detection into `python/flask` and
>   serve two different templates or build a responsive template that
>   switches video-type after measuring screen-width?
>
> 3: How do i do 2?
>
> Sorry, but your questions are to broad to be answered here. You should
>   find a nice book or tutorial for Responsive Webdesign. Maybe a good
>   starter: hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-tutorials –  Klaus D. 5
>   hours ago
>              What do you mean by videoload too high? –  m170897017 5 hours ago
>              I mean that a video is about 1mb and that is too much for mobil. –  Finn Frotscher 5 hours ago
>              @KlausD. I know the basics about Responsive Webdesign. I have worked with bootstrap and build for example link. I just dont know the
>    way to solve this specific problem –  Finn Frotscher 5 hours
>   ago

after this i worked on it some more but made zero progress for hours.
i asked again:

> I build this [App](http://finnfrotscher.pythonanywhere.com/) on `Flask` (hit reload a couple of times). But
>   on Mobile everything breaks down. It neither shows the
>   background-image nore plays the video even though its `.mp4`.
>
> `Responsive Design` for this website doesn`t work, because there is no
>   support for videos on mobile and the screens are a completely
>   different ratio, so the media (video for desktop and img for mobil)
>   has to be served differently.
>
> My idea is to have two templates in my app and make flask render
>   either the mobile or the desktop version, depending on the request.
>
> Is my idea practical? is there a better way?  how can i make
>   `flask/python` recognize mobile?

please help me. i have no idea how to get this website mobile-friendly

Comment: Sorry but reposting questions is frowned upon, if you have new information then update your previous question

Comment: Reasking the question will not help, you need a proper title (if it is a different question) or edit the old question to make it more relevant.

Comment: *"have been trying to figure this out for two days"* - that's really not all that long!

Comment: my problem is that i asked that question and i got no answer...... its not an old question if it has not been answered

Comment: You got no answer because it was too broad a question for SO. Read the guidance in the Help Center (I have provided a link for your convenience) and edit the question (ditto) to bring on back on-topic. Just asking the same question repeatedly, without making the effort to understand **why** you aren't getting answers and **how** you can improve the question, isn't going to endear you to the community.